# Can a probabilistic polynomial time algorithm `A` always be converted into an equivalent non-probabilistic polynomial time algorithm `A'``?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, theory, computation-theory

> Can a probabilistic polynomial time algorithm `A` always be converted into an equivalent non-probabilistic algorithm `A'` that runs in polynomial time?

I need to know whether the above is true for solving a textbook exercise. In the exercise description, I'm given a PPT algorithm `A` and is asked to produce a PT algorithm `A'` for solving a particular problem.

Note that nothing is said whether `A'` is probabilistic or non-probabilistic. I'm uncertain whether the reason is that a appropriate conversion exists, or whether PT is more general than PPT, i.e. a PT algorithm can either be probabilistic or not.

Comment: Why do you write "nothing is said whether A' is probabilistic or non-probabilistic" while the quoted text assumes a "non-probabilistic algorithm A'"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not question on programming.

Comment: Belongs on CS. The relevant keyword is derandomization.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by probabilistic algorithm; for some type of probabilistic algorithms the question is still open and equivalent to the question of whether `BPP=P`.